# Encode 2 single FP values in a double and get them back, in JS

Tags: javascript

I am using the TradingView library, which is a graphic charting tool for trading.

Its API allows passing an array of time + up to 5 numbers per bar (all has to fit in a price candle: Time, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume. I can't play with the time, the library uses it, but I can pass whatever numbers in the last 5 values
)

When it's time to draw the charts, I get back the 5 numbers in a callback.

I would like to pass 10 numbers, and I can accept some loss of precision.

Is there a clever way to do the following steps in JS:

- convert two f64 numbers to two f32 floats
- cast the two f32 to two i32
- pack the two numbers into an i64
- pass it through the API
- reverse the whole thing later

There wouldn't be any difficulty to do that in C/C++, but I have no idea how to achieve that in JS.

Comment: Maybe [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Typed_arrays). You can probably skip the f32 step.

Comment: Doesn't it very much depend on what that mystery library _does_ with those numbers…?!

Comment: "*I am using a JS library in which I can pass 5 numbers through the API [...]*": What library?

Comment: @deceze the library is TradingView which is a graphic charting tool for trading. it allows passing an array of up to 5 numbers per bar, the data will go through untouched. Then, when it's time to draw the charts, I get back the 5 numbers in a callback. Essentially all has to fit in a price candle: Time, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume. I can't play with the time, the library uses it, but I can pass whatever numbers in the last 5 values.

Comment: Sure you can do something like this, but how about modifying the library so it supports passing through an arbitrary number of values? Less hacky, probably useful to other people if you contribute it back.

Comment: @Ry-, I can't modify it. It is not the open version, but one under license which is not provided to the public, for which we get regular updates. Unfortunately, I have to follow the format they set.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution in the end:

```
const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(8)
const f64    = new Float64Array(buffer)
const f32    = new Float32Array(buffer)

// pack two f32 into one f64 number
export function Pack2 (a, b) {
    f32[0] = a
    f32[1] = b
    return f64[0]
}

// unpack two f32 from one f64 number
export function Unpack2 (n) {
    f64[0] = n
    return [f32[0], f32[1]]
}
```